# Adding a "return to shop" button on single product pages that leads back to product parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

My client wants to place a "return to shop" button on single product pages in WooCommerce that leads back to **the previous page** and not the main shop page.

I have explained that all browsers have back buttons but they are dead set on having this button. I've even mentioned activating breadcrumbs but they don't like those either.

How can I achieve That.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a new user welcome, Please [**get this really quick tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn basically how things works here on SO. Then may be you can have a look at this: [**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/). Thanks

Comment: "Return to stop" seems misleading if you're not returned to the shop page. And if the products are in one than 1 category how will you decide which category to send people back to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the category id by using bellow code and then add if condition to show the like

```
$product_category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
```

Comment: Can you please the ready to use code. One that just need to copy and paste. Or at least give me some tips to use the above mentioned code. Thank you.

Comment: I used this code `<?php

$product_category = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

$category_id = get_cat_ID( $product_category );

$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-lg manage-btn " role="button" title="Return">Return</a>` but I get the url of the product instead of the url of the category. Can you please advise me on that? Thank you!